# How to I transfer a video from Node editor to the 3D View?

Tags: node-editor, 3d-view

[image]

(I'm new to blender)
So I've erased the green-screen off of a video in Node Editor.
Now I just need to use the actual video and animate it in the 3D View. But I don't know how to transfer it from the node editor to the 3d view.

Comment: Hello :). I'm afraid it's not possible to link images/videos from compositor to the 3D viewport. The compositor is applied *on top* of your renders. You can, however animate it first, and then mask out the green screen in the compositor.